# Eclipse settings to sync and save a single project over multiple paths

Tags: java, eclipse, path, project, synchronization

I can't seem to find a setting in Eclipse to save and back-up a single Project to multiple paths.

I have a single Java Project in Eclipse that I save on my local machine and either *save as...* or *copy replace* to a local network **and** local mass storage, for BACKUP. I'd like that to occur on any, all Project *saves*.

I saw Project properties, but I'm not too familiar with Eclipse and team dev options, and I don't want to F the paths, links, etc.

Thanks.

EDIT: I'll try what user101 recommended, but to avoid confusion, My own personal, primary Linux box is where development is performed. The other locations are, for lack of a better word, BACKUPS. I used the term "Sync" for the sake of what my question may be related to.

Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that you want the sources from different paths , if so You can try as below

1>  Create new java project

[image: new project window]

2>  Click on link additional source

[image: link src window]